# ng $resource Fails to Dynamically Generate URI

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

### The Problem:

I have code to set up a $resource that seems to compile without error:

```
var ReportsRest = $resource('/reports/:reportId', {reportId: '@id'});
ReportsRest.get({id: 123});
```

but when that code actually executes the request url that is generated looks like this:

```
GET http://localhost:5523/reports?id=123 404 (Not Found)
```

The id is not being parsed and dynamically loaded into the URI.  Is there something that I am missing?

### Plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/3ikqMsnDI9r9LThaQLf3?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ReportsRest = $resource('/reports/:reportId', {reportId: '@id'});
ReportsRest.get({reportId: 123});
```

Under [$resource Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage), there is this block of text.

`paramDefaults`

> Default values for url parameters. These can be overridden in actions methods. If any of the parameter value is a function, it will be executed every time when a param value needs to be obtained for a request (unless the param was overridden).
>
> Each key value in the parameter object is first bound to url template if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search query after the ?.
>
> Given a template /path/:verb and parameter {verb:'greet', salutation:'Hello'} results in URL /path/greet?salutation=Hello.
>
> **If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value for that parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the data object** (provided when calling an action method). For example, if the defaultParam object is {someParam: '@someProp'} then the value of someParam will be data.someProp.

To summarize, the object you pass in needs to use the *key* of your `paramDefaults` object to get the value. That value replaces the same `:key` text in your URL pattern. Any value in the `paramDefaults` object that is prefixed with an `@` will be set on the returned model data as a property named whatever follows the `@`.

```
var ReportsRest = $resource('/reports/:reportId', {reportId: '@id'});
ReportsRest.get({
    reportId: 123,
    other: 123
}, function(data) { /* ... */ });
```

This makes a request to `/reports/123?other=123`. `data`, in the callback, looks like `{ id: 123 }`.

Comment: After playing around a bit it seems to me that the '@id' value will not be set on the returned model, but if you call an action method on the model object (ie. report.$save(); ), the url parameter for reportId will be taken from report.id when generating the URL for the POST.